# Chrome on Android doesn't offer to open PDFs when opened in new tab after a delay

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, pdf

Apologies that this is a long question, I wanted to make sure it was clear what the problem is and, just as importantly, what it isn't - because I know there are a lot of questions that seem related but they don't seem to be about quite the same issue:

The web application we're developing at work needs to open a URL in a new tab when the user presses a particular button, after an API request has completed. The URL in question happens to open a PDF document.

We're aware of the issue with popup blockers, so are opening a blank tab straight away when the button is pressed, then setting the location to the URL a short time later after the API request completes. And this is working fine on desktop browsers as well as on Safari on iPad.

But there is a peculiar problem with Chrome on Android - at least we have observed the problem on Galaxy tablet versions 6 and 7. I'm aware that for some reason Chrome on Android does not have a built-in PDF viewer - however, it seems that accessing the PDF should trigger the OS to ask the user which app they want to use to view the PDF, and we are OK with that. What we do not want - but what is happening at the moment - is the PDF simply getting downloaded in the background, and the user not being given the option of viewing it directly.

From my research on how browsers handle PDFs, it seems this behaviour is dependent on various response headers - notably Content-Type and Content-Disposition. But we are doing this correctly as far as I know - the Content-Type is application/pdf and there is no Content-Disposition header so it should default to "inline", ie opening up to view rather than downloading. And I have tried adjusting the backend to send this header explicitly, both with and without a filename parameter - with no change in observed behaviour.

I strongly suspect this is a bug with Chrome and/or Android, but I cannot find it clearly reported anywhere. The key thing is that there is a delay in setting the URL - because if I put this directly into the console (which I can do when running browserstack from my desktop; not sure if there's any way to input it into a real device directly):

```
 function test1() {
     window.open("url/for/my/pdf");
 }
```

this works fine (the device prompts you with a choice of how to open the PDF)

but not with either

```
function test2() {
    const newTab = window.open();
    setTimeout(() => {
        newTab.location = "url/for/my/pdf";
    }, 1000);
}
```

or even with this, non-asynchronous, version:

```
function test3() {
    const newTab = window.open();
    newTab.location = "url/for/my/pdf";
}
```

Both test2 and test3 above, when called from the console, result in the PDF being downloaded rather than viewed. And this isn't specific to our endpoints - I've tested it with URLs to various random PDF documents I've found online, and the same behaviour occurs.

So my questions are:

1. is this a known bug with Chrome or Android?
2. whatever the answer to 1) above, is there any straightforward workaround which will ensure the user is always prompted to open an application to view the PDF, rather than simply downloading it? (Bearing in mind that we can't avoid the delay between opening the tab and setting the location - or at least this is our preferred way.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You enabled automatic download instead of 'ask every time'.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there - are you saying there's a device or browser setting that controls this? I don't think it's as simple as that because it behaves as we want when opening PDFs directly from a URL but not when setting the location via Javascript in a new tab at a point after the tab is opened. Surely if there was a setting on that always downloaded then function test1 in my question would also download - but it doesn't.